# How can I create a wrapper for the RecyclerView Adapter that will accept any Adapter that implements RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

I know the title is a bit weird, sorry. This is a weird one that I'm not even sure I can explain it correctly, here is my attempt:

Basically I want to implement a wrapper for any adapters that extend `RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>` , the wrapper eventually will be able to insert rows if needed and it will modify things like `getItemCount()` as necessary, but I'm nowhere near that part yet.

This is my class definition:

```
class MyRecyclerAdapterWrapper(activity: Activity,val originalAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
```

I pass to it the original adapter which I want to wrap.

If I have the class definition like that, and then I try to create an instance of `MyRecyclerAdapterWrapper` like this:

```
val wrapper = MyRecyclerAdapterWrapper(activity, myOriginalAdapter)
```

Where `myOriginalAdapter` is an instance of:

```
class MyOriginalAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyOriginalAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
```

I then get an error saying that it is expecting `RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>`  but instead got `MyOriginalAdapter`.

So then I tried the `out` keyword on the class definition like this:

```
class MyRecyclerAdapterWrapper(activity: Activity,val originalAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<out RecyclerView.ViewHolder>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
```

And that allows my constructor call `MyRecyclerAdapterWrapper(activity, myOriginalAdapter)` to stop complaining, however then my `MyRecyclerAdapterWrapper` class fails at implementing some of the `RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>` overrides because `originalAdapter` expects `Nothing` instead of `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`.

For example inside `MyRecyclerAdapterWrapper` I have this piece of code:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        originalAdapter.onBindViewHolder(holder,position)
}
```

The error here is `Type mismatch` `Required: Nothing` `Found: RecyclerView.ViewHolder`.

So what is the correct way to handle this?

Edit: just wanted to be clear that other adapters will also use this wrapper, so the wrapper must be generic.

Edit: I should have mentioned this, there is a similar wrapper that works fine that I was using but it is in Java, the class definition on that one was:

```
public final class MyRecyclerAdapterWrapper extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{
     public MyRecyclerAdapterWrapper(@NonNull Activity activity,
        @NonNull RecyclerView.Adapter originalAdapter){
```

Edit: Based on the answer from @muetzenflo I was able to get most of it to work but still have a problem with some methods.

I now have this:

```
class MyRecyclerAdapterWrapper<T : RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(activity: Activity, val originalAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<T>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
```

And

```
 class MyCustomAdapter(): RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCustomAdapter.MyViewHolder>(){
        class MyViewHolder(v: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {

        }
```

This works:

```
val myRecyclerAdapterWrapper = MyRecyclerAdapterWrapper(this, MyCustomAdapter())
```

But this doesn't:

```
genericMethod(myRecyclerAdapterWrapper)

private fun genericMethod(myRecyclerAdapterWrapper: MyRecyclerAdapterWrapper<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>) {

    }
```

The error is:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is MainActivity.MyRecyclerAdapterWrapper<MainActivity.MyCustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> but MainActivity.MyRecyclerAdapterWrapper<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> was expected
```

Edit: Think I figured out how to make the generic methods:

```
private fun <T> genericMethod(myRecyclerAdapterWrapper: MyRecyclerAdapterWrapper<T> ) where T : RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    }
```

**So in the end this is how my class ended up and it all compiles and runs:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val myRecyclerAdapterWrapper = MyRecyclerAdapterWrapper(this, MyCustomAdapter())
        genericMethod(myRecyclerAdapterWrapper)
    }
    private fun <T> genericMethod(myRecyclerAdapterWrapper: MyRecyclerAdapterWrapper<T> ) where T : RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    }
    class MyRecyclerAdapterWrapper<T : RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(activity: Activity, val originalAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<T>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            return originalAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(parent,viewType)
        }
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            originalAdapter.onBindViewHolder(holder as T,position)
        }
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return originalAdapter.itemCount
        }
    }
    class MyCustomAdapter(): RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCustomAdapter.MyViewHolder>(){
        class MyViewHolder(v: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
        }
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `MyOriginalAdapter.MyViewHolder`  might be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are my 2 classes that I use in all of my projects for making generalized use of databinding in RecyclerView items:

#### Usage

```
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import de.bvb09.android.R
import de.bvb09.android.data.model.news.NewsComponent
import de.bvb09.android.recyclerview.DataBindingAdapter
import de.bvb09.android.recyclerview.DataBindingViewHolder

/**
 * This adapter is responsible for the optional horizontal image gallery
 */
class ZoomImageAdapter : DataBindingAdapter<String>(DiffCallback) {

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return R.layout.item_zoom_image
    }

    /**
     * The DiffCallback is used by the [DataBindingAdapter] to check which items are
     * completely new and which just changed its content. When defining the Boolean checks, be
     * as precise as possible to avoid strange behaviour of the RecyclerView items.
     */
    object DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<String>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: String, newItem: String): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: String, newItem: String): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
}
```

##### The ListAdapter

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter

/**
 * This generic Adapter can be used to use any data class T as data provider for recyclerView list items.
 * To send a list of items to this adapter, use the submitList(newList) method. The DiffCallback is then called to
 * detect which items are completely new or have changed content. Animations are created accordingly and automatically.
 */
abstract class DataBindingAdapter<T>(diffCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<T>) : ListAdapter<T, DataBindingViewHolder<T>>(diffCallback) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DataBindingViewHolder<T> {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ViewDataBinding>(layoutInflater, viewType, parent, false)
        return DataBindingViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DataBindingViewHolder<T>, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(item)
    }
}
```

##### The ViewHolder

```
import androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import your.package.name.BR

/**
 * This ViewHolder is an addition to the [DataBindingAdapter]. From this, it receives a ViewDataBinding which
 * allows us to connect the data class T with the data-bindings defined in the item layout.
 */
class DataBindingViewHolder<T>(private val binding: ViewDataBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    var item: T? = null
        private set

    fun rebind() {
        binding.invalidateAll()
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }

    fun bind(item: T) {
        this.item = item
        binding.setVariable(BR.item, item)
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I took what you did and sort of applied it to my code and it mostly works. I made my class like this: `class MyRecyclerAdapterWrapper<T : RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(activity: Activity, val originalAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<T>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>()` but the only problem is that now I need to have a generic method somewhere else that accepts `MyRecyclerAdapterWrapper` and it won't let me. I'll update my question with the code and error.

Comment: So using your example I was able to make it work and added an edit showing how my classed ended up looking.

Comment: Good to hear! If you need to bind more objects than just "item", you can always create more `bind()` methods binding to BR.xxx

Answer (score 0):

parameter require `Nothing` because you declared `out` for generic parameter

try to change `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` to `MyOriginalAdapter.MyViewHolder`

```
class MyRecyclerAdapterWrapper(activity: Activity,val originalAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<MyOriginalAdapter.MyViewHolder>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyOriginalAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyOriginalAdapter.MyViewHolder {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyOriginalAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        originalAdapter.onBindViewHolder(holder, position)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: While that change would probably fix it, I can't do that because this needs to be generic. Other adapters will also use this wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, this should solve your issue in a generic matter.

Your `RecyclerViewWrapper` can use generic types for both the `Adapter` and for the `ViewHolder`

```
class RecyclerViewWrapper<VH : RecyclerView.ViewHolder, A : RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>>(
    activity: Activity,
    val originalAdapter: A
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VH {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VH, position: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

Your `OriginalAdapter` can be whatever adapter you want

```
class OriginalAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

And then to use it you can just initiate it as such

```
fun example(activity: Activity) {
    val wrapper = RecyclerViewWrapper(activity, OriginalAdapter())
}
```

I think this will be able to help you (as long as I understood correctly), you may need to make minor changes to fit your needs but nothing breaking

Comment: This appears like it will work, I'll have to modify a bit of code though as now it wants me to specify the type of `RecyclerViewAdapter` everywhere, for example I have a method that uses the adapter and the only way I'm getting it to compile is like this `fun useRecyclerViewWrapper(adapter: RecyclerViewWrapper<RecyclerView.ViewHolder,out RecyclerView.Adapter< RecyclerView.ViewHolder>>)`

Comment: Where do you have this function? and also, if you do make some changes, let me know and I'll update the answer to reflect your needs better

Comment: It is just some helper functions I have. For example for the current java adapter I have a function that looks like this `fun registerAdatper(adapter: RecyclerViewWrapper) {

    }` The functions are not even on the same file, they on some helper objects.

Comment: In that case these functions can also use the generic types and that should help with that

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean?

Comment: Yeah, every function that you will use with the Generic types '<>' most of the time it will be auto-cast to whatever you need so you can put any adapter that you want and it will accept it, that is because we are declaring both the adapter and the ViewHolder as generic and we set the adapter to use the generic viewholder, same as how it works in the constructor, that's why I didn't need to define anything else

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241912/discussion-between-gil-goldzweig-and-casolorz).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below wrapper class of recycler view adapter,

```
public class WrapperRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private final RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

    public WrapperRecyclerAdapter(RecyclerView.Adapter adapter) {
        super.setHasStableIds(adapter.hasStableIds());
        mAdapter = adapter;
        mAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new ForwardingDataSetObserver());
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return mAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        mAdapter.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mAdapter.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        mAdapter.onViewRecycled(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        mAdapter.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        mAdapter.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        mAdapter.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        mAdapter.onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return mAdapter.getItemId(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mAdapter.getItemCount();
    }

    private class ForwardingDataSetObserver extends RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver {

        @Override public void onChanged() {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override public void onItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            notifyItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount);
        }

        @Override public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
        }

        @Override public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(positionStart, itemCount);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition, int itemCount) {
           notifyDataSetChanged(); //TODO
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I already have this in Java, I'm looking for how to do it in Kotlin.

Comment: Okay but you can convert above class to Kotlin and then use accordingly

Comment: That is what I did and it doesn't work, which is why I posted the question.